# jQuery ajax adds query string that Code Igniter fails on

Tags: codeigniter, jquery

I'm making an ajax request using jQuery that looks like this:

```
$(function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        // In my actual code the following is an absolute URL
        url: "messages/1/new",
        cache: false
    });
});
```

(`messages` is the action, `1` and `new` are arguments)

Using FireBug, I found the problem that the actual URL being sent is like `messages/1/new?_=1293985116579`, but CodeIgniter creates a 404 error on this.

So, I would like to either (A) stop jQuery from appending the query string, or (B) set CodeIgniter to accept or ignore the query string.

Comment: are you using post method or get? also what is your `enable_query_strings` config setting? I prefer setting it to false and just use POST..also i suppose `messages` is you r method name and `1` & `new` are the parameters?

Comment: Right, `messages` is the method name, and `1` and `new` are parameters.  Thanks, I'll edit that to be clearer.  Is the `enable_query_strings` setting you're talking about in `system/application/config/config.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so this question has an answer... codeigniter really prefers POST data. Make sure you send parameters using POST not GET when using Ajax and it will make things much easier!

Comment: Okay, hope you enjoy your freebie!

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the question mark in your Codeigniter config file as an allowed character so the get requests don't throw an error. You should still use POST data if possible though!

Comment: I didn't know that, so thanks.  And I'll keep that POST tip in mind as well.  Thanks!